# Mongodb query to add a review into reviews

Tags: mongodb

hi i have made a query to add a new review into the reviews array of an existing listing. this is the code im working with and i dont know where i went wrong with it . the second part is the example reviews

```
db.listingsandreviews.updateOne[
    {reviews:{
      "_id": "58663769",
      "date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1451797200000"
        }
      },
      {"listing_id": "10006546",
      "reviewer_id": "51483090",
      "reviewer_name": "Michelle",
      "comments": "The place was really nice and the host are friendly with us"
    }}}]
```

```
_id
"403055315"
date
2019-01-20T05:00:00.000+00:00
listing_id
"10006546"
reviewer_id
"15138940"
reviewer_name
"Milo"
comments
"The house was extremely well located and Ana was able to give us some …"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what the problem is, but from the description you may be missing $push operator to add review into existing reviews.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#examples

If you can provide proper queries that you run and problem, we may be able to help better, for example currently "updateOne[" will cause error, as it should be "updateOne(".

Comment: hi so i have changed it to using the ( ) brackets but it still shows and error. i have updated the code into looking like this yet it still shows an error. 
```db.listingsandreviews.insertOne({"_id:1006546}, {"$push":
    {reviews:{
      "_id": "58663769",
      "date": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1451797200000"}},
      "listing_id": "10006546",
      "reviewer_id": "51483090",
      "reviewer_name": "Michelle",
      "comments": "The place was really nice and the host are friendly with us"
    }}})```

Comment: Error: clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.
this is the error message i receive

Comment: Please make sure code that you paste here is properly formatted.
From this query, first quote seems not closed 

{"_id:1006546}  -->  {"_id":1006546}.

Not sure what the error means using just this information

Comment: Hi im still new on stack overflow so im still quite confused on how to use it. I did not realise that mistake i did.  but is the query to do it correct?

Comment: Other parts seem good, but not clear why you use numberLong for dates, instead of just directly using dates like this 'new ISODate("2022-10-16")' in "date": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1451797200000"}} part .